# When you find out what I am, you'll be very angry

Tags: riddle, word

> I am one step away from stealing your things,
>   And two steps away from selling you out.
>
> I am one step away from judging you,
>   And two steps away from killing you.
>
> When you find out what I am,
>   You'll be very angry.
>
> What am I?

Comment: I hope I won't be angry like this https://xkcd.com/169/.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe that you are

> irate

because you are

> one step away from being a **pirate** (+p) who steals things
>  two steps away from being a **rat** (-ie) who ratted me out
>  one step away from a **rate** (-i) which could be good or bad
>  and two steps away from being **nitrate** (+nt) which is a deadly explosive

Comment: Correct! I had "IRA" for the last one (they're an Irish terrorist group) but I honestly think "nitrate" works better. Well done!

Comment: @F1Krazy It can be argued [Nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrate) itself isn't explosive, although a key element in many explosives (the 'enabler', provider of oxygen). Nitrate esters are explosive (and even those not always, they can for example be used in medicine).